# My table td vertical border doesn't appear

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a table to display all my subjects content.

My table td vertical border doesn't appear, below is the css code.

Please help.

```
table.subjects {
border-width: 1px;
border-spacing: 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: gray;
border-collapse: collapse;
background-color: white;}

table.subjects th {
border-width: 1px;
padding: 1px;
border-style: inset;
border-color: gray;
background-color: white;
-moz-border-radius: ;}

table.subjects td {
border-width: 1px;
padding: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: gray;
background-color: white;
-moz-border-radius: ;}
```

Comment: where is the value for -moz-border-radius????

Comment: vertical border can appear if u add <table border="1">....</table>

Comment: Here's what I'm seeing...http://jsfiddle.net/n79GE/ I changed the td border color to red and it looks like it's visible.  What is the issue you are seeing?

Comment: I didn't change anything, and it is visible! http://jsfiddle.net/shahverdy/7S6Jr/

Answer (score 0):

in html you shoud set border of attribute of table to 1 . did you do it?
it is solution:

```
<table border="1">
```

Comment: Agha javid, in ke asan dare kar mikone khodesh

Comment: salam mostafa bayad border table ro set kone ta kar kone.mesalesho test kardi?

Answer (score 0):

you can use css class like

.tableborder{
border:1px solid gray;

}